# How to start timers from the worker thread class in Qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt, timer, qthread

**Declaration part of Controller class:**

```
class ProtocolPacket: public QQuickItem
{
private:

    Q_OBJECT

    ...
    QThread objWorkerThread;

public:
    ProtocolPacket();
    ~ProtocolPacket();
...
```

**The constructor of controller class:**

```
ProtocolPacket::ProtocolPacket()
{
    ReadWriteSerialPort *objReadWriteSerialPort = new ReadWriteSerialPort;
    objReadWriteSerialPort->moveToThread(&objWorkerThread);

    connect(&objWorkerThread, &QThread::finished,
            objReadWriteSerialPort, &QObject::deleteLater);

    /// Following signals of ProtocolPacket class are connected to the corresponding
    /// slots of thread class ReadWriteSerialPort.
    connect(this, &ProtocolPacket::cameraValueChanged,
            objReadWriteSerialPort, &ReadWriteSerialPort::receiveAndSendUpdatedCameraValue);
    ...
    ...
    objWorkerThread.start();
}
```

**The constructor of worker thread class:**

```
ReadWriteSerialPort::ReadWriteSerialPort()
{
    ...
    serialPort.setPortName ("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serialPort.setBaudRate (QSerialPort::Baud19200);

    if(serialPort.open (QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    }

    objWriter = new SerialPortWriter(&serialPort);
    objReader = new SerialPortReader(&serialPort);

    timerSendVelocityPackets = new QTimer(this);
    connect (timerSendVelocityPackets, SIGNAL (timeout()),
             this, SLOT (sendVelocityPacket()));

    timerSendHealthFeedbackPackets = new QTimer(this);
    connect (timerSendHealthFeedbackPackets, SIGNAL (timeout()),
             this, SLOT (formAndSendHealthFeedbackPackets()));

    timerReceivePackets = new QTimer (this);
    connect (timerReceivePackets, SIGNAL (timeout()),
             this, SLOT (receiveAndUnpackPacket()));
    timerReceivePackets->start (300);
}
```

I am receiving the error:

`QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`

What am I doing wrong?

I wish to start the timers from the worker class: ReadWriteSerialPort

Comment: The constructor of QThread runs in the calling thread, not the thread the QThread instance belongs to. So you have to start your timer somewhere else, after starting your worker thread.

Comment: Please explain your comment in more detail and a solution too in an answer.  @KarstenKoop

Comment: The comment is incorrect.

Comment: The error is not visible in the code you posted. Obviously something is trying to start a timer from a different thread than the thread this timer belongs to. Could be the result of creating objects in `ReadWriteSerialPort` without setting `this` as the parent, or maybe you just call a function that is meant to run in a different thread from the main thread, or vice versa.

Comment: @thuga please tell, do I have to set "this" as parent for timer also? I have created the timer in the worker class. Is that not enough?  Why?

Comment: I don't think the error you are getting is from `timerReceivePackets->start (300);` since the line is sure to be executed in the same thread that created the timer ( the creation and calling `start` are in the same function ) . So, Where are you starting your other timers? is that happening in `ReadWriteSerialPort::receiveAndSendUpdatedCameraValue`?

Comment: Also, do you inherit `ReadWriteSerialPort` from `QObject`? would you please post its header file?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without a complete, self-contained test case that reproduces the issue. None of the code you show indicates any sort of an issue, and in any case you're just dumping your code on us. For code to be fit to be included in a question, a serious amount of work usually has to be made on it - often resulting in you finding the solution yourself. Developing a good, minimal test case is simply good debugging practice whether you ask a question here or not.

Comment: Right now my hunch is that you call methods of `ReadWriteSerialPort`, or methods of its sub-objects, from other threads, but these methods that you call are not thread safe. Instead of direct calls, you'll need to use signal-slot connections, or `QMetaObject::invoke`, etc.

Comment: You already set `this` as the parent for the timers. So this is probably not the problem. However, you might be calling some function that starts one of these timers, from the main thread.

Comment: @thuga thanks. I have found the source of the problem, but I don't know how to correct it. Will post reproducable example soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every object constructed in the object that you move to another thread must have its parent set:

```
class ReadWriteSerialPort : public QObject {
  QSerialPort serialPort { this }; // important
  QTimer timerSendVelocityPackets { this }; // etc.
  ...
};
```

You also must ensure that there are **no direct calls into the thread-unsafe methods of `ReadWriteSerialPort`** from other threads.

Furthermore, unless you're polling for data, the timer-driven packet receive is incorrect. You should act on the `readyRead` signal issued by the serial port.

I also question the separate reader and writer: Usually these tasks both need to be aware of the expected state of the target device, so separating them might be unhelpful. It's hard to say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: Serial port is also declared and initialized in the worker class. Though idon't have pointer of serial port. I can post the whole code if you want.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Post a minimum test case that reproduces the issue. We don't need the entire code. Remove every statement not needed to show the problem, and put everything into a single `main.cpp` file. I expect to see less than 100 lines of code.